# Cocos2d - running a scene a second time doesn't schedule updates

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

From a UIKit ViewController I do this to start a game:

```
if (director.runningScene == nil)
    {
        [director runWithScene:[MyGameLayer scene]];
    }
    [director startAnimation];
```

MyGameLayer looks like this:

```
+(id) scene {
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    MyGameLayer* layer = [MyGameLayer node];
    [scene addChild:layer z:0 tag:GameSceneLayerTagGame];


    return scene;
}

-(id) init {
    if ((self=[super init]))
    {
        NSLog(@"init!");
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        [self initPhysics];

        [self scheduleUpdate];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The first time I play the game, everything works fine. `-(void) update: (ccTime) dt` gets called as it should. If I exit the game and do this:

```
CCDirectorIOS* director = (CCDirectorIOS*)[CCDirector sharedDirector];
    [director stopAnimation];
    [director end];
```

And then play the game again, `-(void) update: (ccTime) dt`does not get called, even though I know `-init()` is getting called. The game appears on the screen, but the update scheduling doesn't work the 2nd time around. What would cause Cocos2d to not schedule the update and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out. When opening the menu in the game which has the quit button, I was pausing the game like this:

```
[[self gameLayer] pause];
```

So when I would start a new game, Cocos2d was still paused, even though the scene and layers were deallocated and I was creating a new glView.

If I use this it works:

```
[[self gameLayer] pauseSchedulerAndActions];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you override (implement) one of the `onEnter*`/`onExit*` methods? If so, make sure you call the super implementation otherwise scheduling and touch input may not work.

**Update:**
Other than that try not calling [director end] because it shuts down cocos2d completely which is known to be problematic.

Comment: If I don't call [director end], the 2nd time I start the game I just get a pink screen. Followed by an endless stream of openGL errors: OpenGL error 0x0501 in -[CCSprite draw] 532

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are doing what you are doing to prevent the director from updating with the 4 fps when working in background, you should maybe try to start the director again.

That being said, in your applicationDidBecomeActive, add the following code

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation]; // call this to make sure you don't start a second display link!
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
```

Taken from: [How to implement pause/resume in cocos2d game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082718/how-to-implement-pause-resume-in-cocos2d-game)

If I am incorrect please let me know what you are trying to do with your director calls

Comment: I have a view controller that has multiple mini games to choose from. So I need to be able to quit one game and start another. The problem is that the update scheduler only works on the first game I play. No animation happens on any subsequent plays of the same game or any other.

Answer (score 0):

When you 'pause' your game by using this code:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]pause];
```

You also have to 'resume' your director in the restart or menu code block before pushing any scene:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]resume];
```